# How i can open (.it) file?

Tags: c++

I am doing a Project in Communication field by using Ubuntu 13.04. The project executed by simulation and the output will be in the format of .it files.

some body could help me , how can I open these files ?

Comment: can your IDE not open the file?

Comment: No i dont know how i open file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[About IT++](http://itpp.sourceforge.net/4.3.1/)

> IT++ is a C++ library of mathematical, signal processing and
>   communication classes and functions. Its main use is in simulation of
>   communication systems and for performing research in the area of
>   communications. The kernel of the library consists of generic vector
>   and matrix classes, and a set of accompanying routines. Such a kernel
>   makes IT++ similar to MATLAB, GNU Octave or SciPy.

[Writing and reading data from files](http://itpp.sourceforge.net/4.3.1/itfile.html)

> Here we will use the it_file class to store some data. The program
>   write_it_file.cpp looks as follows: ... When you run this program you
>   will obtain a file called it_file_test.it in your current directory.
>   You can read the file into Matlab/Octave to view the data by using the
>   following commands:
>
> ```
> itload('it_file_test.it') 
> figure(1); 
> clf; 
> plot(a)
> ```

And then they give an example of a C++ program to read an .it file. So it seems your options are:

- Use Matlab
- Use GNU Octave
- Write a reader in C++